# Async/await not supported in protocol extension?

Tags: swift, async-await, uikit, protocol-extension

In my iOS application, I have a protocol extension that is similar to the following:

```swift
protocol ViewControllerBase: UIViewController {
}

extension ViewControllerBase {
    func showItem(itemID: Int) {
        Task {
            await loadItemDetails(itemID)

            let itemDetailsViewController = ItemDetailsViewController(style: .grouped)

            present(itemDetailsViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func loadItemDetails(_ itemID: Int) async {
    }
}
```

I'm using a protocol extension so that all of the view controllers that implement `ViewControllerBase` will inherit the `showItem()` method. `ItemDetailsViewController` is defined as follows:

```swift
class ItemDetailsViewController: UITableViewController {
}
```

The call to `loadItemDetails()` compiles fine, but the calls to the `ItemDetailsViewController` initializer and `present()` method produce the following compiler error:

> Expression is 'async' but is not marked with 'await'

This doesn't make sense to me, since the initializer and method are not asynchronous. Further, I'm using the same pattern elsewhere without issue. For example, if I convert `ViewControllerBase` to a class, it compiles fine:

```
class ViewControllerBase: UIViewController {
    func showItem(itemID: Int) {
        Task {
            await loadItemDetails(itemID)

            let itemDetailsViewController = ItemDetailsViewController(style: .grouped)

            present(itemDetailsViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func loadItemDetails(_ itemID: Int) async {
    }
}
```

It seems to be related to UIKit specifically, because this code also compiles fine:

```swift
class ItemDetails {
}

protocol Base {
}

extension Base {
    func showItem(itemID: Int) {
        Task {
            await loadItemDetails(itemID)

            let itemDetails = ItemDetails()

            present(itemDetails)
        }
    }

    func loadItemDetails(_ itemID: Int) async {
    }

    func present(_ itemDetails: ItemDetails) {
    }
}
```

Is there a reason this code would not be allowed in a protocol extension, or might this be a bug in the Swift compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doesn't make sense to me, since the initializer and method are not asynchronous.

True, but there is another situation in which you have to say `await` and the target method is treated as `async`: namely, when there is a cross-actor context switch.

Here's what I mean.

What's special about UIKit, as opposed to your ItemDetails / Base example, is that UIKit interface objects / methods are marked `@MainActor`, requiring that things run on the main actor (meaning, in effect, the main thread).

But in your protocol extension code, there is nothing that requires anything to run on any particular actor. Therefore, when you call the ItemDetailsViewController initializer or `present` method, the compiler says to itself:

"Hmmm, we might not be on the main actor when this code (`showItem`) runs. So these calls to ItemDetailsViewController methods could require a *context switch* [changing from one actor to another].)"

A context switch is *exactly* when you need to treat the called method as `async` and say `await`; and so the compiler enforces that requirement.

The simple way to make that requirement go away here is to mark *your* method as `@MainActor` too. That way, the compiler knows there will be *no* context switch when this code runs:

```
extension ViewControllerBase {
    @MainActor func showItem(itemID: Int) {
        Task {
            await loadItemDetails(itemID)
            let itemDetailsViewController = ItemDetailsViewController(style: .grouped)
            present(itemDetailsViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func loadItemDetails(_ itemID: Int) async {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. But why is that required for the protocol implementation, and only for UIKit-derived types?

Comment: The compiler knows that the ItemDetailsViewController initializer and `present` methods will run on the main thread. But it has no way of knowing what thread type (main or non-main) _this_ function will run on unless you tell it. And if this function were to run on a non-main thread, we'd need a context switch (`await`). So the compiler  assumes that the context switch might be needed — unless you assure it otherwise.

Comment: Makes sense. Adding `@MainActor` does indeed resolve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add the info from that comment to the actual answer, so that it stands a better chance of helping others.